Subfloor causing poor air quality
As a long-time asthma and allergy sufferer, I’ve been struggling with air quality issues after moving into a ground-floor apartment, which was built in the 1950s in Yugoslavia. The apartment has a parquet floor laid over something I can best describe as 15-cm subfloor filled with sand. After renovating, which included installing PVC windows and remodeling the walls, the air has become quite stuffy and dusty. It feels like dirt is evaporating through the holes in the parquet. Unfortunately, there’s no HRV or ERV ventilation system.
The builders who visited were impressed with the quality of the parquet and advised against changing it. When I suggested removing the subfloor altogether, they mentioned it would be a tedious and costly job.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to improve the air quality without such drastic measures? Thanks in advance!

Open the windows.  Any place will become stuffy if kept closed up.

That's what we're doing for now, but it won't be possible once winter sets in.

Temporarily cover the floor in plastic to see if it is the floor that is causing the air quality issues.

Interesting idea! Thanks!
